# Getting error "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<String>"

Tags: apex

I have a `Apex Class` with following code.

```
global class MyClass{
    global string myMethod(){
        String[] lablesArray = new String[]{'Expensive','Call','Room','Raliabity','Performance','Nurses','Security','Care','Doctors','Emergency','Recovery'};
        Integer[] vals = new Integer[]{277,221,109,125,120,73,76,61,112,156,72};
        list<DataSet> data = new list<DataSet>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i< lablesArray.length; i++){
            DataSet d = new DataSet();
            d.lable = lablesArray[i];
            d.val = vals[i];
            data.add(d);
        }
        return JSON.serialize(data);
    }

    virtual class DataSet{
        String lable;
        Integer val;
    }
}
```

when I try to save it I am getting following error

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`length` is not a property of list in salesforce, use `size()` method.

Change:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < lablesArray.length; i++){
```

to:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < lablesArray.size(); i++){
```

Always try to understand the error message, and documentation are best place to look for it. Please refer [List Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm).